# Print a Hyphen/Dash?

Tags: c++

How to print hyphens to an output like this for ex, 344-34-4333. If this ID is read from a file that has the number without hyphens, how can I get it to print xxx-xx-xxxx 3 to 2 to 4 ?

Comment: That's how: `std::cout << "-";`

Comment: To turn `334344333` into `344-34-4333`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string` class has a lot of constructors to help you with these problems. The `substr()` member function is also useful.

A quick and dirty example:

```
std::string x("344344333");
std::string res = x.substr(0, 3) + '-' + s.substr(3, 2) + '-' + x.substr(5,4);
```

For more complex strings, you'll probably prefer to use the `std::ostringstream` class.

Comment: If I have a list of ID numbers in a file and I read the data from the file(included as 344344333) and I wanted to for example print 344-34-4333. I need help with how to do this while looping in the file. I tried using modulus, etc. but can't seem to get it.

Comment: @user3078999: No need to do complex math when you are dealing with chars, just strings and offsets. Something like `std::ifstream f('data.txt'); std::string x; while (std::getline(f, x)) { /* transform and write x as in the answer */ }`.